# Unable to add dependencies in Android Studio for Flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Actually i'm going to make run time permission for my Flutter project only for android section. So that I have done following procedure.

Added permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Added the `android.support` dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'}'
```

Manually Import the package in `MainActivity`

[image]

Still the error is showing.

**Note : after add the dependencies is not show any alert to sync the gradle file.
       i don't know to manually sync the gradle file while doing flutter 
       project.**

Comment: i am having the same issue, can you please assist if you solved?

Answer (score 1):

- Open your cmd or terminal (Or using built-in Terminal in Android Studio).
- Use cd command to navigate to your android folder.

Then run the command:

> ./gradlew build

Comment: I used above command, and i seen result also `Build Successful`. But that problem is still there . Invalidate catch and restart also done.